# Python post request failing 3

Tags: python-requests

I am trying to make a post request using `python requests` library. The post I am trying to duplicate looks like this in the `chrome` developer tool:

```
:path:/leagueOverview/football/england/premier-league?requestId=5&wsTrack=441d62c066a64465a2f7b03717d2d694&method=post
:scheme:https
accept:application/json
accept-encoding:gzip, deflate, br
accept-language:da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
content-length:6019
content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded

user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36
Query String Parameters
view source
view URL encoded
requestId:5
wsTrack:441d62c066a64465a2f7b03717d2d694
method:post
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
bettingTypeIds:7
bettingTypeIds:8
bettingTypeIds:9
```

and my code with error looke like this

```
headerbb = {'accept':'application/json' ,\
'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, br',\
'accept-language':'da-DK,da;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',\

'content-length':'6019',\
'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',\
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) \
          Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()  
url1 = 'https://bbfeapi.betbrain.com/leagueOverview/football/england    /premier-league?requestId=5'
url2 = url1+'&wsTrack=' + wsTrack+'&method=post'
formdata = {'bettingTypeIds': ['7','8','9'] }

session.post(url2, headers=headerbb,data=formdata )
```

This is giving me an errorcode `500`. My guess is that I am doing something wrong in the `formdata`, but how do I write this `formdada` in the right way? I might also be doing something wrong in the header

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but here's a little catch-all approach for replicating HTTP-requests recorded in chrome:

In the Chrome Dev-Tools, right-click on the request you want to replicate and click "**Copy as cURL**", then go [here](http://curl.trillworks.com/#python), select "python" as the language and paste in the curl-command.
This will output python (-requests) code that should be ready to go. If session-cookies are required, you might have to change the code around a bit to use a requests-session (as you did in your example) and request some page before doing the POST.

If this doesn't help get you to the solution, please edit your question to include the cURL you copied from chrome.

**Edit:**

Please try this code and see if it works for you.

```
import requests, json
from pprint import pprint

headers = {
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'origin': 'https://www.betbrain.com',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,de;q=0.4',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'authority': 'bbfeapi.betbrain.com',
    'cookie': 'visid_incap_878444=0IWvPeyoSiOyl15h8NeUkmcBFlgAAAAAQUIPAAAAAACClzFL2y3zI3kGh0UF9iBb; incap_ses_289_878444=CLx3JSblzwMcgYYoVbwCBGcBFlgAAAAA9gzkJrI33q8daHr8iP7XrQ==; JSESSIONID=AF30CFE0653AECB1A20CFACD686E8A4F; incap_ses_184_878444=FRwnZDjTa0wAxRtNVOWNAhQYGVgAAAAAOjOVH1A2ipnR7gEwfzvGsg==; oddsFormat=EU; bookieNameAndLogo=NAME_LOGO; showOddsWithCommission=false; gmtTimezoneOffset=0',
    'referer': 'https://www.betbrain.com/football/england/premier-league/',
}

data = {
  'bettingTypeIds': '7,8,9,11,12,13,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,32,33,34,35,37,39,45,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,57,60,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,87,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130,131,132,133,134,135,136,137,138,139,140,141,142,143,144,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,154,155,156,157,158,159,160,161,162,163,164,165,166,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,192,193,194,195,196,197,198,199,200,201,202,203,204,205,206,207,208,209,210,211,212,213,214,215,216,217,218,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,238,239,240,241,242,244,245,246,247,248,249,250,251,252,253,254,255,256,257,258,259,260,261,262,263,264,265,266,267,268,269,270,271,272,273,274,275,276,277,278,279,280,281,282,283,284,285,286,287,288,289,290,291,292,293,294,295,296,297,298,299,300,301,302,303,304,305,306,307,308,309,311,312,313,314,315,316,317,318,319,320,321,322,323,324,325,326,327,328,329,330,331,332,333,334,335,336,337,338,339,340,341,342,343,344,345,346,347,348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358',
  'domain': 'www.betbrain.com'
}
parameters = {
    "requestId": 1,
    "wsTrack": "eabad591a6c44ecf94a81287ba246920",
    "method": "post"
}
response = requests.post('https://bbfeapi.betbrain.com/leagueOverview/football/england/premier-league?', params=parameters, headers=headers, data=data)
print response.status_code
pprint(json.loads(response.text))
```

Comment: Ty Moorztech that helped me somewhat :-) I found a website where you can  get the python code from curl: http://curl.trillworks.com/ .

Comment: Ty Moorztech. :-) I found a website where you can  get the python code from curl: http://curl.trillworks.com/ . If i paste the curl there i get a script that works. However i still have a problem: i am trying to scrape https://bbfeapi.betbrain.com/leagueOverview/football/england/premier-league?requestId=5&wsTrack=76f779cc70684bb392d313912a2c0503&method=post. here wstrack is obtained in a response from https://bbfeapi.betbrain.com/httphs?method=get. The only cookie used is JSESSIONID which is also set there and i use a session to keep the cookies. I still get response 500...any idea why?

Comment: @PerRavn could you please add the cURL-expressions you are copying from chrome to your question? Also, just to clarify, you are trying to scrape the events/odds from https://www.betbrain.com/, correct?

Comment: It works! However i am a litle concerned it won't work tomorrow when the wsTrack has expired? For this reason i have tried to get the wstrack and jSESSIONID like this: session = requests.Session()  
postmand = session.get('https://bbfeapi.betbrain.com/httphs?method=get')
sessPostRes = postmand.json()
wsTrack = sessPostRes['wsTrack']
sessionId = session.cookies['JSESSIONID']. Then i changed the parameters to parameters = {..."wsTrack" : wsTrack ...} and cookie to 'cookie': '...JSESSIONID='+sessionid+'...' however this does not work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Anyone? How Can i automatically get the wstrack needed to get the data from https://bbfeapi.betbrain.com/leagueOverview/football/england/premier-league?requestId=5&wsTrack=76f779cc70684bb392d313912a2c0503&method=post

Comment: Could i use selenium to somehow get the wstrack?